# Python getter не возвращает значение

Tags: python, python-3.x, setter, getter, property

У меня тут не работает пример из книги.

[image: Пример из книги]

Вот мой код

```
class Duck():
    def __init__(self, input_name):
        self.hidden_name = input_name

    @property
    def name(self):
        print('Inside the getter')
        return self.hidden_name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, input_name):
        print('Inside the setter')
        self.hidden_name = input_name
```

В оригинале когда пишем `fowl.name` должно напечататься

```
inside the getter
'Howard'
```

А у меня печатается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`return` не возвращает строку `'Howard'` или `'Jon'`.
Когда использую `print(fowl.name)` то все работает нормально, но в книге же не используют `print`.
Это ошибка книги или я что то не правильно делаю? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё у вас в порядке, `return` возвращает всё, что он должен возвращать

Просто в книге пример целиком выполняется в интерактивном режиме (на это однозначно указывают символы `>>>` или `...` в начале каждой строки с кодом). Вы же пример записали в файл, а интерактивный режим используете только для того, чтобы запустить этот файл на выполнение.

Отличие интерактивного режима в том, что если написать в строке выражение, то интерпретатор не только выполнит это выражение, но и сразу выведет его результат. При исполнении файла такого не происходит - всё, что вы хотите вывести, вы должны выводить явно через `print`, или иным способом.

Поэтому если хотите, чтобы у вас было всё в точности как в книге, то вы можете работать целиком в командной строке. Но, имхо, проще продолжать работать со скриптами в файле, просто помнить, что он сам не будет выводить результат выполнения каждой строки, а только то, что явно выводится через `print`.